# Hide MATLAB figure in the taskbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created a lot of MATLAB figures, using the `figure` command. All these figures appear as icons in the taskbar (see below). I would like to hide these icons in the taskbar, but the figures themselves should still be visible on the screen.

[image: MATLAB figure icons in taskbar]

Any solution for this?

Comment: You could use [subplot or something similar](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/combine-multiple-plots.html), otherwise no, there is no easy way to hide a window in the task bar from MATLAB.

Comment: Too many plots to use `subplot` and and they are already "grouped" functionally (many graphs in one plot as might be visible from the screenshot). However, I don't mind to have a not so "easy" solution, e.g. involving the underlying Java-Awt-Swing framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the figures, set the `WindowStyle` property to `docked`:

```
for k = 1:10
    figure('WindowStyle','docked');
end
```

This way all the figures will open in the main Matlab window, in different tabs, so you won't see them in the taskbar. See below the peek-view from the taskbar at the bottom that previews only 2 windows. Next, you can choose the 'float' option in the Figures window:

[image: float button]

and then you can arrange all the figures as you wish:

[image: Figures window]

Comment: With this solutions the figures have same sizes, so it wouldn't look that good. In addition it is necessary that I can arrange the plots such that I can compare things and this would be quite difficult or even not possible

Comment: Looks good :-). Is it also possible to add a customized menu bar at each plot as you can do when a figure is not docked?

Comment: @Domenico I think you may get a better (and quicker) answer if you will ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/48320) from their forums, you can hide the entire menu bar using:

```
set(<handle>,'menubar','none');
```

I am not at my machine currently so I cannot test it.

Comment: This hides the pull-down menus on the figure.  It has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: Good call. That's what I get for responding without testing.